# Redirecting If Item Config Item Set To False Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have on codeigniter a config item called 
`$config['system_installed'] = TRUE;` or `$config['system_installed'] = FALSE;`

What is the best way to make it redirect to a server sub folder in library. example something like `SERVERURI "/" 'install'`

Is set `$config['system_installed'] = FALSE;` will redirect to `SERVERURI "/" 'install/index.php'`

Comment: where did you put the $config variable? on the `config` or a custom one?

Comment: in the config.php in codeigniter application

Comment: Are you updating the config file to TRUE after the installation process? Is `install` a Codeigniter controller?

Comment: it would be better if you have something like `config_install.php`

Comment: Redirect to a server sub folder in library, what you mean? You can't access CI's library by `HTTP`.

Comment: I have a sub folder which has its on application and index.php so example url would be localhost/project/install I use for installer and it writes replaces the config file if all is true.

Comment: @WesleyMurch Yes the config item gets replaced to true via install if install is success full but just trying to work out best way to make redirect if set false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand:

- The `/install` URI is a directory with it's own application, independent of CodeIgniter
- The installation process updates the CodeIgniter `config.php` file, setting `$config['system_installed'] = TRUE;`

If this is how you have to do it, create a base controller in `application/core` called `MY_Controller.php`:

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/core_classes.html

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {
  function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
    if ( ! config_item('system_installed')) redirect('install');
  }
}
```

You'll have to update all your controllers to `ControllerName extends MY_Controller {}`

You could even just do the redirect right in the config file (as the only content) if you are replacing the entire contents of it. It's dirty but who cares, the file will only exist for a few minutes while you install your application.

---

I want to suggest an easier way though. Forget about `$config['system_installed']`.

In your root `index.php`, just redirect to `/install`, have that be the only code:

```
<?php
header('Location: install');
exit;
```

Then have your installation process update your `index.php` with the actual CodeIgniter `index.php` content instead of updating the config file. Keep a dummy copy of the CI index.php somewhere in the install directory (name it whatever) and copy the content over with PHP, then you can even have `/install` self-destruct after installation.

Comment: I use HMVC though. Can my_controller work with HMVC MX.

Comment: Yeah, just have `MY_Controller extends MX_Controller {}`

Comment: And redirect('install'); folder for this is out side of applications folder has its applications and index.php my directory like application, download, image, system, index.php, install -> application, index.php

Comment: Yep got it, it should work fine. `/install` is at the same level as CI's `index.php` right?

Comment: I added this  header('Location: install/index.php'); exit; to index.php main one but is set true now. But still blocks me off from viewing website/server.

Comment: I don't really get what you mean now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54688/discussion-between-wesley-murch-and-acoderslife).

Comment: I fixed issue did not need to add the index.php part works Great Now.